# Golang, перезапуск функции после завершения предыдущей

Tags: golang

Мне нужно сделать так что бы функция запустилась, отработала и через определенное время снова запустилась.
Я попробовал реализовать этот функционал следующим образом:

```
func timeout(t time.Duration, cmd func()) {
    c := make(chan bool, 1)
    var task = func (){
        cmd()
        time.Sleep(t)
        c <- true
    }
    go task()

    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            go task()
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу подсказать насколько верна эта реализация и, если есть более правильный/оптимальный вариант, показать пример.
Так же возможно есть библиотеки которые позволяют реализовать данное поведение для запуска по CRON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простое исполнение делается намного проще:

```
func setInterval(d time.Duration, f func())
    for {
        f()
        time.Sleep(d)
    }
}
```

Если же вам нужно что-то, что работает по более точному расписанию, можете воспользоваться пакетом [`github.com/robfig/cron`](https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron):

```
c := cron.New()
c.AddFunc("0 30 * * * *", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour on the half hour") })
c.AddFunc("@hourly",      func() { fmt.Println("Every hour") })
c.AddFunc("@every 1h30m", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour thirty") })
c.Start()
```

Comment: Я пробовал воспользоваться предложенной вами библиотекой до того как создал здесь вопрос. Я не смог найти как сделать так что бы функция выполнялась только после того как завершится предыдущая при правиле `*/5 * * * * *`. Может подскажите возможно это или нет?

Comment: @Bleser Вам в таком случае нужен какой-то семафор. Хоть даже элементарный буль под мутексом.